# Checking whether a string contains a certain character

Tags: php, mysql

I'm constructing a transport related site and want to check whether a service operates on a certain day. I have column called "operating_days" in my database with "1234567", "12345", "67" etc as entries with 1 indicating Monday, 2 indicating Tuesday and so on.

A query like below would be helpful but of course with a working command to check the string.

```
$operating_query = "SELECT departure_point FROM services WHERE operating_days LIKE '3' AND trip_number LIKE '" . $_SESSION['book_trip_number'] . "'";
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Change `operating_days LIKE '3'` to `operating_days LIKE '%3%'`. Unless you use `%` symbol as wildcard, search will be performed for full matching. You may also require similar change for `trip_number` field.

Comment: Share DB structure...and with some raw values and desired output...

Comment: @OP: Read [documentation on LIKE clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

Comment: @RavinderReddy That works perfectly, thank you for your help!